# using ggplot2 to get heatmap of catagorical variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using:

```
ggplot(Book2, aes(State_short, NIC))+ geom_tile(aes(fill = emp_grth_cat), colour = "white")+ labs(title ="Growth of Employment by States and NIC", x = "States", y = "Sector")+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1.0))
```

to get a heatmap of `emp_grth_cat` which is a discrete variable, plotted against States and NIC.

[image]

How do I change the colour scheme to 8 shades of grey?

Answer (score 1):

I add some dummy data to reproduce the case. The idea is to use scale_fill_manual() and pass your color palette to a function:

```
    library(ggplot2)

    Book2 <- data.frame(State_short = c(rep("Arizona", 10), rep("Aiowa", 10), rep("Wisc", 10)),
                    NIC = rep(LETTERS[1:10], 3),
                    emp_grth_cat = c(rep(1:8, 3), rep(1:6, 1)))

    ggplot(Book2, aes(State_short, NIC)) + 
      geom_tile(aes(fill = factor(emp_grth_cat)), colour = "white")+
      scale_fill_manual(values=c('#ffffff','#f0f0f0','#d9d9d9','#bdbdbd','#969696','#737373','#525252','#252525')) + # here is the custom pallete
      labs(title ="Growth of Employment by States and NIC", x = "States", y = "Sector", fill = "emp_grth_cat")+ 
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1.0))
```

[image]

Comment: Should this be `scale_fill_manual` not `scale_colour_manual`, as the variable is mapped to fill?

Comment: @JonMinton, good point. Sure it should be scale_fill_manual().